# How to charge car on driveway with EVSE inside the garage?

Tags: electrical, garage, driveway

I installed an EVSE (hardwired Wallbox Pulsar Plus 40A) inside my garage due to HOA but I park my car on the driveway. What options do I have for charging my car other than relocating the EVSE outdoors or parking inside? I can think of:

1. Run the cable under the garage door protected with a "garage door cable protector" (e.g. [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BWVHZQWM) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09F13GL3D) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BSN6RPKC) etc). The problem is I think the garage door won't fully close.
2. Make a hole on the wall and use a "cable pass through port" or an "RV cable hatch" (e.g. [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B017KWL4IM)). The hatch needs to be big enough to fit the EV connector. I found quite a few reddit posts of using an RV cable hatch but there were a few comments that it might not be up to code even though their installation was done by a licensed electrician and passed inspection.
3. Make a small hole on the wall to fit just the cable. Have a small "cable pass through port" or a conduit.
4. Run the cable through the mailbox slot similar to the low voltage cables for my cameras, see photos.

I'm leaning towards option 4. Most in my HOA are doing option 1 but with a thinner cable than mine. There is one doing option 4. What are the pros & cons of these options? Do any of these options violate any electrical code? I'm in California.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Low voltage cables you can do what you want, there is very little code that deals with them.  High voltage(house) cables/wires must go by code.   Is there any problem with putting the car in the garage for charging?   Quite sure NEC rules will over ride/over rule any HOA rules, same as roof top antennas.

Comment: The garage is full with random stuff and no space for the car. I'm looking for electrical code compliant options that don't involve parking the car in the garage or moving the EVSE outdoors.

Comment: Type of EVSE and amp size will give the experts more information.

Comment: Good point. I edited my question. It's a hardwired Wallbox Pulsar Plus 40A.

Comment: I suspect the answer will be "swap the existing outlet for a junction box and run conduit and THHN through or across the wall to the exterior location where you want the charger."

Comment: Changed from "what do you recommend?" (which is [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) because it's opinion based) to "What are the pros & cons?" because that will get you some pretty specific items that you can then form _your_ opinion on.

Comment: Usually HOAs limit the installation of outdoor chargers in shared areas including private spaces that are tightly packed, parking lot style. In your picture it looks like you have a private driveway and garden? Not part of a common area? I'm curious what HOA rule prevents you from putting the charger on the wall next to the mailbox, and what the reasoning was. There should be a reason, and knowing it will help you figure this out.

Comment: Driveway is private but not the garden. It's complicated. Consider yourself lucky not being part of HOA. Anyway I understand you want to help and provide alternatives but let's keep the constraints: EVSE is in garage, car is on driveway, how to charge car with the door closed?